# How to ido double spacing WITHIN references using \natbib

Tags: natbib, line-spacing

I am trying to have doublespacing across an entire document,  including the spacing within each reference. `\doublespacing` seems to work for everything except within a single bibliography item, and I cant seem to make it work. I am using the `natbib` package - I have the bibliography style set to `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

Much help appreciated.

Best

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. You mention the macro `\doublespacing`; does this mean that you employ the `setspace` package? Incidentally, a comment such as "I cant seem to make it work" is not actionable. Please be more specific as to *what* isn't working. Do you get any error and/or warning messages? if so, what do they say? Please also clarify what you mean by "a single bibliography item". E.g., is there incorrect line spacing in just one bib item?